# Pandas: reading column by supplying header names

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to retrieve a column from Excel sheet.
Below is table which has 4 headers, i.e., 4 columns.
I need to retrieve column `h3`. Is there any way I could do this with Pandas?

```
h1  h2  h3  h4
2   Q   21  20.3
1   A   32  2.3
3   W   21  34.2
9   R   42  9.3
```

Comment: I see answer was reaacepting, what is reason?

Comment: although yours was absoluetly right, recent one was more descriptive. Just to help out someone who dont know this, I have reaccepted. Cheers mate. I have posted another question just now. Please let me know if you know the answer.

Comment: Ok, I think now my answer is more descriptive, also explanation why `sheetname='Sheet1'` is not obviouslt necessary.

Comment: accepted  cheers mate :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is necessary create DataFrame by [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) - `sheetname` is not necessary specify if need first sheetname of file:

```
df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx')
```

Use for Series selecting by `[]`:

```
s = df['h3']
```

Use for one column DataFrame  selecting by double `[]`:

```
df1 = df[['h3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read excel file using pandas and just print out a list using DataFrames.

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
print(df['h3'])
```